# QML property value propagation when using a popup with "parent: Overlay.overlay"

Tags: qt, qml

Consider this:

```
Item {
    Material.primary: red
    Item {
        Popup {
            parent: Overlay.overlay
            Component.onCompleted: {
                // Not the correct value
                console.log(this.Material.primary)
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Correct value
        console.log(this.Material.primary)
    }
}
```

I understand why `Popup` is getting the wrong `Material.primary`, because it's parent is different than the declared hierarchy.

I could manually set `Material.primary` in `Component.onCompleted`, but I'd run the risk of accidentally not setting it.

If I were to create a `CustomPopup` that is simply a `Popup`, what code what I need to add to ensure that `Material.primary` is propagated from the declared heiarchy (in QML), as opposed to the actual hierarchy (`Overlay.overlay`)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. You have to reference the `Item` which you think should be the parent by `id`

```
Item {
    id: item1
    Material.primary: "red"
    Item {
        Popup {
            Material.primary: item1.Material.primary
            parent: Overlay.overlay
            Component.onCompleted: {
                // Also the correct value
                console.log(this.Material.primary)
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Correct value
        console.log(this.Material.primary)
    }
}
```

**EDIT after PO-comment**

In case you want to create a separate CustomPopup.qml you could actually wrap the Popup in an `Item` since you are parenting the Popup to the `Overlay` anyway. The wrapper then takes the roll of child who inherits the `Material.primary` property.

```
Item {
    id: wrapper

    Popup {
        parent: Overlay.overlay
        Material.primary: wrapper.Material.primary

        Component.onCompleted: {
            // Not the correct value
            console.log(this.Material.primary)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The key issue is that I want to create a custom component that internally sets the correct ```Material.primary``` color. Within the component, I won't have access to any ideas outside of the component.

Comment: Typo, "any ids outside"

Comment: @PaulKnopf ah, I kinda missed that from your question ;-) I have updated my answer